# 'EvenNumbers' object has no attribute 'num

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why this error shows up while trying to run a *while* loop (like a *for* loop) in my iterator:

```py
import time

class EvenNumbers:
    def __init__(self, max=None):
        self.max = max
    def _iter_(self):
        self.num = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.max or self.num <= self.max:
            result = self.num
            self.num += 2
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration

def run():
    evennumbers = EvenNumbers(5)
    while True:
        try:
            element = next(evennumbers)
            print(element)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except StopIteration:
            break

if __name__ == '_main_':
    run()
```

This is the error:

```
(venv) brunoalexco@Brunos—MacBook—Air pythoncourse3 % python3 iterator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brunoalexco/Desktop/code/pythoncourse3/iterator.py", line 37, in <module>
    run()
  File "/Users/brunoalexco/Desktop/code/pythoncourse3/iterator.py", line 31, in run
    element = next(evennumbers)
  File "/Users/brunoalexco/Desktop/code/pythoncourse3/iterator.py", line 20, in __next__
    if not self.max or self.num <= self.max:
AttributeError: 'EvenNumbers' object has no attribute 'num'
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Alright, I'm new here. Thanks for the commendation.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `self.num = 0` inside of the `__init__()` function.

Comment: Yup, it fixed the error. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please make this the correct answer if it fixed your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should add `self.num = 0` inside of the `__init__` function